# Problems with shared preference-flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I wanna ask how to save state from textfield? cause i can't saving this state, after hot restart my value always reset, i just want to save state after hot restart, can i know my problem where it's wrong?

it's my code:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  var nama = 'nama';
  void setPref() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(nama, nameController.text);
  }

  void load() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      nama = prefs.getString(nameController.text) ?? '';
      nameController.text = nama;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    load();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    .....
  }
}
```

Comment: if you just want to initialize the texfield with text you can do it as follows `TextEditingController(text:'name');`

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code:
In shared Prefrences you have to use key to store and get value.
But you are using it in wrong way:

Here is correct code:

```
void load() async {
var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String value = '';
setState(() {
  
  value= prefs.getString(nama) ?? '';
  nameController.text = value;
});
}
```

The `nama` is a key name and you are also using it to receive value. And the key you are using is `nameController.text` is also wrong.

**Bonus**

The convection of writing keys in Flutter is Following:

```
String nameKey = 'NAMEKEY';
```